# power management of USB-enclosed hard drives

Tags: linux, ubuntu, power-management, usb-drive, external-hdd

With a typical USB hard drive enclosure, is the full range of drive power management functionality available?

**edit**: moved this into a [separate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5387/how-to-avoid-powering-down-certain-usb-devices-when-a-machine-is-suspended):

<s>In what may be an unrelated matter: is it possible to suspend a PC without unmounting an attached USB-powered drive, and then remounting it on resume?  This is the behaviour I'm currently seeing (running Ubuntu linux 10.10).</s>

**/edit**

Are there certain models or brands that provide more complete control over this aspect of drive operation?  My Friendly Neighbourhood Computer Store carries (part of) the Vantec Nexstar product line.

Comment: [cross-posted on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/228325/power-management-of-usb-enclosed-hard-drives)

Comment: [cross-posted on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19804/power-management-of-usb-enclosed-hard-drives)

Comment: I think you took out the only part of this question that made it on-topic; the rest is probably best on SU

Comment: @Michael: you may be right.  Well, feel free to delete, it's already cross-posted over there.  I guess the rationale for keeping it here would be that the enclosure's power management functionality has to be accessible from *n*x, i.e. not controlled by custom Windows drivers.

Comment: The SuperUser cross-post has an answer...